# I have some question of surface in differential geometry with implicit function.

Tags: differential-geometry

In differential geometry,

Let $M : g(x,y,z)=c$. Then if $dg$ is not zero at any point of $M$, then $M$ is a surface

My question is why if $dg=0$ for some point of $M$, then we can not state that $M$ is surface.

In class, if $dg=0$ for some point of $M$, level set can have a volume.
Hence $M$ is not surface.
But it's so hard to understand this statement.

Q1.If $dg = 0$ at any point on surface $M$, please tell me an example that $M$ is not a surface.

Q2. Please explain if $dg=0$ for some point of $M$, level set can have a volume.

Comment: As for question (2), "can have a volume" is not very precisely, but notice that the level set $g^{-1}(0)$ of $g(x, y, z) := 0$ is just the domain of $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not be a *smooth* surface. Consider the cone
$$x^2+y^2-z^2=0$$
and what happens near the origin.

Here's an example where you drop dimension completely (you were going the wrong direction with trying to raise dimension). Consider 
$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2=0$.